# Why is it such a mess with mimetypes?

Tags: mime-types, venn-diagram

I'd like to create a database table populated with mimetypes and related known extensions.

Here is a Venn Diagram I've just created:
[image: Mimetypes Venn Diagram]

Can we rely on libmagic for identifyng file for security purposes ?

It seems Libmagic is aware of a very small part of "all known mimetypes".
For Libmagic I've used:

```
find ~/file-5.14/magic/Magdir/ -type f -exec grep '!:mime' "{}" \; > /tmp/mime.log
```

Where file-5.14 is the source code of Linux **file** command.

For Apache I've used [mime.types file](http://svn.apache.org/repos/asf/httpd/httpd/branches/2.4.x/docs/conf/mime.types):

For IANA, I've used [IANA Media Types](http://www.iana.org/assignments/media-types/media-types.xhtml)

There is a bias in my methodology ?

Comment: What's the question, exactly?

Comment: There is a bias in my methodology ? especially, the way I get all mimetypes in libmagic lib ? There is less than 300 mimetypes in it...

Comment: I'm surprised by the difference between standard mimetypes references such as IANA media types and tools like libmagic...

Comment: @Azman0101 Probably no one has taken care of identifying the remaining ones, or they are too hard to identify?

Comment: There is no God of Mimetypes. That's why. People make them up when they need them. If they get popular, they might be registered by IANA. Libmagic identifies the ones that (1) the maintainers find important enough to bother with, and (2) that they can implement a good heuristic to detect